# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment which is not referenced

Tags: python

```
def foo() :
     for i in range(0, 5):

            path2 = "data." + str(i) + "\\log." + str(i)
            file = path + path2

            try:
                if  os.path.getsize(file) > 0:
                    print("All good")
                    f=open(file)
                    string=f.read()
                    pattern="(cd\s/[a-zA-Z0-9]*.*)"
                    matches=re.findall(pattern,string)
                    for input in matches:
                        print(input)
                        a=input.split(";")
                        x=len(a)
                        print(x)
                        cmd.append(x)

                        y=0
                        if y <= x:
                            y=y+1
                            print(a)
                            listofcmd.append(a)
                            continue

                print(cmd)
                print(listofcmd)
                dictionary=dict(zip(cmd,listofcmd))
                print("Number of commands : List of Commands")
                print(dictionary)
                for k,v in dictionary.items():
                    print(k,v)
                row=c.fetchall() 
                c.execute('''INSERT INTO log (Numberofcmds, Listofcmds)
                                         VALUES (?, ?)''', (k,v))
                conn.commit()
                sqlstr1=('SELECT (Numberofcmds, Listofcmds) FROM log ')
                for row in c.execute(sqlstr1):
                    print(str(row[0]), row[1])




            except OSError:  
                 print("File not found")    

     i=i+1
     return i

foo()
```

I want to insert the data into the database and i am getting a unboundlocalerror for the variable 'k' which is not referenced outside the loop. What might the problem here? 
I tried to insert session id and time similarly i did not face any problem but now when i'm trying to add this data i m continuously getting this error how much ever i change.
  Error :
VALUES (?, ?)''', (k,v))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'k' referenced before assignment

Comment: If `dictionary.items()` is empty (so the dictionary is empty), nothing is ever assigned to `k` (or `v`). Perhaps you meant to execute that SQL statement inside the loop?

Comment: It *is* referenced outside the loop, no? `c.execute('''INSERT INTO ...''', (k,v))`

Comment: I want the values of k,v to insert into the database, When i use it in the loop i am getting : error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: When i am just printing out the k,v values i have the values which are needed but when i am trying to insert those values into the database i am getting those errors. I'm stuck here.